# can't insert xml dml expression as a string

Tags: sql-server-2005, xml-dml

Here is the code below that would explain you the problem...

I create a table below with an xml column and declare a variable, initialize it and Insert the Value into the xml column,

```
create table CustomerInfo
(XmlConfigInfo xml)

declare @StrTemp nvarchar(2000)

set @StrTemp = '<Test></Test>'

insert into [CustomerInfo](XmlConfigInfo) 
values (@StrTemp)
```

Then comes the part of the question,, if I write this...

```
update [CustomerInfo] set XmlConfigInfo.modify('insert <Info></Info> into (//Test)[1]')
```

-- Works Fine!!!

but when I try this,

```
set @StrTemp = 'insert <Info></Info> into (//Test)[1]'

update [CustomerInfo] set XmlConfigInfo.modify(@StrTemp)
```

-- Doesn't Work!!!

and throws an error

*The argument 1 of the xml data type method "modify" must be a string literal.*

is there a way around for this one?

I tried [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlxml/thread/810e8b6a-a169-487c-840d-6e37b7f39f7d), but it is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

AS it usually comes out, Dynamic SQL is something that has always come to my rescue :)

but much to my anxiety, considering t-sql is interpreted,  why not make tsql more like a dynamic language itself, **can any one suggest why such strong typing in t-sql**?

here is the [link](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.sqlserver.xml/topic57129.aspx) that has a few options solutions regarding the problem,

Solution I used:

> Execute sp_executesql @StrQuery